# how to redirect page using java script

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

m using java srcipt messagebox..

```
private void MessageBox(string msg)
    {
        System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label lbl = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label();
        lbl.Text = "<script language='javascript'>" + Environment.NewLine + "window.alert('" + msg + "');</script>";
        //lbl.Text = "<script>window.alert('" + msg + "');</script>";
        Page.Controls.Add(lbl);
    }
```

now i want to reload my page..but if i write response.redirect my messagebox is not display....i write this function in code behind and call it when i need to display messagebox...so, how can i reload my page???????

Comment: don't use `Label`for that, use `<asp:Literal>` Web Control, `Label` Control always escapes stuff...

Answer (score 3):

Like this

```
lbl.Text = "<script>window.alert('" + msg + "');window.location.replace('yourotherpage.aspx')</script>";
```

But please don't forget to properly escape the quotes in your "msg" text. Otherwise you may get a broken script code.

Comment: i use quotoes but it cant work properly it gives error ; expected

Comment: it's missing a `;` after the replace method: `window.location.replace('yourotherpage.aspx');`

Comment: @ jaymz :i can done that  but it still gives error ; expected